# Сигналы, сокеты и fgets

Tags: c, linux

При чтении в программе на Си функцией `fgets(str,sizeof(str),input)` из сокета она может быть прервана сигналом в середине чтения строки. Часть строки уже занесена в str.

Можно ли каким-либо способом (кроме самого примитивного - забить всю `str` перед чтением ньюлайнами) узнать сколько символов занесено в нее к моменту прерывания ?

Может что-то полезное можно вытащить из `struct _IO_FILE` (из `libio.h`) ?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что либо никак, либо ну очень хитро. Не проще ли просто читать read'ом, обрабатывая считанные байты? Или нужно строго fgets?

Comment: И зачем это вообще нужно? Прерывание означает, что чтению конец. Всё. А что получилось в буффере не определено никем. Поэтому лучше не делать так и считать, что мы ничего не прочли.

Comment: @mikillskegg, читать read'ом строки протокола - это реализовывать свой fgets. 

Вообще конкретная задача связана с таймаутами и обработкой других (возможных) сигналов в pthreads. Собственно я сейчас и думаю,  как проще все сделать. Альтернатива прерыванию fgets от "чужого" сигнала это правильное управление sigprocmask в потоках обработки и обработка "общих" сигналов в main. 

@cy6erGn0m, в общем случае это не так. Например SIGCHLD от "фонового" процесса или SIGHUP от администратора, сообщающего об изменениях в конфигурации и т.п. событий, не связанных с данным чтением.

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем-то - да, что-то полезное можно вытащить из `_IO_FILE`.

Мне несколько раз этот вопрос попадался на глаза, но только сейчас я понял, что пару лет назад у меня был аналогичный вопрос: **как определить, где остановился парсер после неудачного возврата из `fscanf`**, чтобы правильно сдвинуть строковый буфер (сетевой пакет).

Решение тогда пришло эмпирически: после очередного вызова `fscanf` я заглянул в структуру `FILE` и обнаружил, что `_iobuf::_ptr` как раз указывает на последний символ, который не соответствует шаблону. Для `fgets`, полагаю, это будет первый несчитанный из буфера символ.

Если каждая строка файла не длиннее файлового буфера, то размер строки можно вычислить, посчитав разницу между "старым" и "новым" `_iobuf::_ptr`.

Хотя вопрос с пометкой `linux`, обращаю внимание на характерные сходства в обеих структурах:

в `Windows`:

```
struct _iobuf {
        char *_ptr;
        int   _cnt;
        char *_base;
        int   _flag;
        int   _file;
        int   _charbuf;
        int   _bufsiz;
        char *_tmpfname;
        };
```

и в `Linux`:

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;           /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

Скорее всего, Вас должен интересовать `_IO_FILE::_IO_read_ptr`

Comment: Ну, хм. Это годится только для конкретной реализации `FILE`. В общем случае требований на содержимое `FILE` нету.

Comment: Хотя конечно если другого метода нет...

Comment: Этот метод тоже не спасет, если прерывание возникнет после записи в `dst`, но перед сдвигом `ptr`. Формально, конечно все будет в порядке: не сдвинут `ptr`, значит, ничего не прочитано. Но и пользы тут мало - большинство таких прерываний будут фиксировать **нулевой размер считанных байт**.

Comment: Если задача действительно требует такой точности, то ко всему вышеописанному, надо еще мониторить **сдвиг файлового указателя** и по прерыванию ориентироваться на него, чтобы понять, какое было к-во считанных буферов за один вызов `fgets`. В таком случае, ограничение на длину строки снимается, напротив: чем меньше будет файловый буфер, тем больше будет шансов получать **частично считанные строки**.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем документацию на [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) (да, я знаю, cplusplus не очень достоверный источник, но все же) и читаем

> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.

То есть, сама функция добавляет нулевой символ. Поэтому, не нужно забивать нулями - ноль будет в конце строки. А дальше берем обычный strlen и смотрим длину. Это конечно не сильно эффективно, но работать точно будет. И самое главное - более-менее платформенно независимо.

Comment: А разве [там](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) что-то сказано про поведение функции при прерывании?

Comment: @mega, тут скорее надо убедиться, что 0 записывается перед *каждым* `read()` внутри цикла в fgets. Все же реально надо рассматривать только прерывания внутри read  (насколько помню все завершилось написанием аналога fgets)

Comment: Я поизучал несколько различных реализаций fgets. В основном вижу 2 реализации: 1 - использование fgetc, 2 - заполнение буфера (аналог read)с последующим в нем поиска `n`. И в обоих случаях сдвиг файлового указателя производится перед заполнением `dst`.

Comment: Это означает, что прерывание нарушит целостность данных между файлом и `dst`, т.е. в `dst` в момент прерывания вообще может не быть данных, которые уже были считаны из `stream'а`. В такой ситуации, о том, что кто-то там поставит еще и "завершающий ноль", я бы на вашем месте не думал. Проблема будет на уровне консистентности указателей. Но в этом, кстати, проблема и моего метода.

Comment: т.е, да, согласен, необходимо избавляться от посредников (промежуточных буферов) и работать с `read` напрямую. Но, скорее всего, коллизия Вас настигнет и тут: Вы же не сможете обеспечить атомарный одновременный сдвиг файлового и программного указателя. Поэтому вынужден признать, @cy6erGn0m тут прав.

Comment: Можно еще обойтись и без атомарного сдвига, но с подтверждением каждого сдвига дополнительным флагом. Это означает, что потребуется своя реализация `read`, а **последовательное чтение** из файла превратится в чтение из файла **со случайным доступом**. Понимаете, сколько проблем может доставить такая мелочь, как "узнать сколько символов занесено в буфер к моменту прерывания"? )).